# How to Use Component in another js file in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use another js file component in another js file. My code is:

```
import NavComponent from './nevbar.js';
class Data extends React.Component{
   render() {
   const add_button = (<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={() =>this.addUser()}><Glyphicon glyph="plus" /></Button>)
   const nevigation = (NavComponent)
}      
return(
<div>    
    {nevigation}
    {add_button}
</div>
);
}
```

Now const nevigation = (NavComponent) is not displaying on screen. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you do a typo? ```import NavComponent from './navbar.js';``` instead of `nevbar` ? Did you `export default NavComponent` in your `nevbar.js` file ?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: I found solution. Thank you sir both of you